# Search column, if value is not all digits, then cut&paste value to another column same row python pandas

Tags: python, pandas, string, dataframe

Wanted to ask for help on a question that has me twisting. I have a dataframe, three columns. First column is suppose to be all numbers.  If letters exist in the column1 (anywhere in the value) then cut&paste value to 'Column3' within the same row.  I have figured out how to use .loc to filter column for certain values and successfully applied text in column3 saying "value has letters". But can not place code together with the idea to say ( if column1 value != isdigit then cut&paste value to column3 same row).  My current test code searches column1, finds letters in value, then moves value to column3 at bottom of column which I do not want.  I would appreciate some insight on how to use .loc and isdigit together, not sure.  Thanks for taking the time.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
# Create a DataFrame
d = {
    'Column1': ['345634', '3fgh98', '765432', '987ke2', '234654', '09hws4'],
    'Column2': [3, 6, 8, 9, 23, 24,],
    'Column3': ['', '', '', '', '', '',]}

df = pd.DataFrame(d, columns=['Column1', 'Column2', 'Column3'])

test = df['Column1']
for i in test:
    if(str(i).isdigit()):
        continue
    else:
        df.loc[(i), 'Column3'] = i

print(df)

#df.loc[(df.Column1 != str.isdigit), 'Column3'] = str. #test code using .loc and isdigit. Notworking
```

The code above will pick up the value with letters in Column1 and move them to the bottom of Column3. It at least gets the values now I have to figure .loc out to cut from column1 and paste into column3 same row.  Below is a picture of what I would like to have happen.

```
Before:

Column1   Column2   Column3
345634    3
3fgh98    6
765432    8
987ke2    9
234654    23
09hws4    24


After:(What I would like to have)

Column1   Column2   Column3
345634    3
          6         3fgh98       
765432    8
          9         987ke2
234654    23
          24        09hws4
```

I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use, [`Series.str.match`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.match.html) along with the given *regex* pattern and optional parameter `na=False`(to treat `NaN` values as `False`) to create a *boolean mask* that corresponds to the condition where the `Column1` values contains all the digits, then use [`boolean indexing`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with this mask to update the values in `Column1` and `Column3` as required:

```
m = df['Column1'].astype(str).str.match('^\d+$', na=False)
df.loc[~m, 'Column3'] = df['Column1']
df.loc[~m, 'Column1'] = ''
```

Result:

```
print(df)

  Column1  Column2 Column3
0  345634        3        
1                6  3fgh98
2  765432        8        
3                9  987ke2
4  234654       23        
5               24  09hws4
```

Comment: That is Awesome!!  Thank you.  I have a question for you.  Why is the tilde (~m) instead of the variable (m) by itself?

Comment: `~` (tilde) specifically means `not` or `negation`. Here `~m` corresponds to the entries in the `Column1`  which are not entirely made up of digits. You can read more about `boolean indexing`  [`here`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing).

Comment: Hey Shubham, an error popped up when applying to larger DF. ( TypeError: bad operand type for unary ~: 'float').  Your code works great in test env. but errors in line df.loc[~m, 'Column3'] = df['Column1'].  This only difference between test and larger DF is possible blank cells nothing else.  Column1 has cells with all number values & cells with number and letter values, also blank cells.  Column 3, all cells or blank. Could this be something with NaN values? I can not replicate this error in test DF.   Any thoughts?

Comment: I actually tried that after researching the error in stackOF.  It takes all cell values and cut&paste them into Column3.  Basically moves all cells to Column3.  Then deletes all values (all cells) within Column1.  Question??  This report comes from an excel file. If the column type came across as string instead of number, would this thinking play into what you are trying to help me with? Sorry about being a pain.

Comment: @Boomer Can you give me a small reproducible sample, so that i can actually see what's going on..

Comment: Let me see what I can do.

Comment: Hey Shubham, I have a condensed versus of the larger DF and can replicate the error within it.  It consist of an excel file with code listed on sheet two.  Just FYI, when python imports this excel file 'Sheet2'(Code) does not exist.  How can I get this to you?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216974/discussion-between-boomer-and-shubham-sharma).

Comment: Hello Shubham, just wanted to see if you received the link to the excel file? Let me know.

Comment: @Boomee Yes, I have received and edited the answer accordingly please see the chat window for the description of the edit.

Comment: Thank You AND THANK YOU!!!!  Works GREAT on the large DF.  Just AWESOME!!!

Comment: @Boomer Glad i could help :).